# How can use asm() with a const char* instead of a string literal?

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, string-literals

If I'd do that:

```
const char *str = "some assembly instructions";
asm(str);
```

CLion'd say "Expected string literal in 'asm'"

Comment: Use a CPP macro if you want this, or different `asm("stuff")` in different `if` branches instead of setting `str` differently for one `asm(str)`

Answer (score 5):

`asm` is not a normal C function that is called during runtime, but it is a special instruction that emits the assembly code you specify at compilation time. `asm` needs to know the assembly instruction at compile time and this is only possible if the argument is a string literal:

Correct:

```
asm("some instruction");   // "some instruction" is known at compile time
```

Incorrect:

```
asm(str);    // at compile time it is potentially not known where
             // str points to
```

**Conclusion:** you cannot pass anything else than a string literal to `asm`.